# This pattern seems exhaustive, but I'm still getting warnings

Tags: types, recursion, sml

I'm learning sml, and wrote the following simple function:

```
(* Return a list with every other element of the input list *)
fun everyOther [] = []
  | everyOther [x] = [x]
  | everyOther x = let
        val head::head2::tail = x
    in
        head::everyOther(tail)
    end;
```

Which is generating the following warning:

```
! Toplevel input:
!   val head::head2::tail = x
!       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
! Warning: pattern matching is not exhaustive
```

I believe the function can never fail, since `val head::head2::tail` will always work for lists with two or more elements and the case of one element and zero elements is covered. As far as I can tell, this function works as expected. I think the issue might be related to the use of `[]` but I really don't know.

My question is actually three fold:

1. Why does sml think that this is not exhaustive (how am I misinterpreting this)?
2. Is there a case where this function will fail?
3. Am I doing something dumb writing the function this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. SML gives you that warning because it doesn't know that `x` has at least two elements. All it knows is that `x` is a list, it doesn't remember the fact that `x` had to have not matched the first two patterns, to go into the third case.
2. No, the code can not fail.
3. There is no reason to perform the pattern match in the let-statement. You can just put the pattern to the `fun` statement, which will result in less code and remove the warning:

   ```
   fun everyOther [] = []
     | everyOther [x] = [x]
     | everyOther (head::head2::tail) = head :: everyOther tail;
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still trying to wrap my head around what can go in the patterns. Quick question though: Does this remove the warning because putting `head::head2::tail` in the pattern allows sml to know there are at least two elements? Or is there something else at work here?

Comment: @Wilduck It removes the warning because for every value that a list can have, there's a pattern matching it. When you did `val head :: head2 :: tail = x` that was not the case because that pattern match only had one case for lists with at least 2 elements.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. In 15 minutes you just demystified something that I had already spent a half an hour on. Thank you again.